# Why is immutability set on types (rather than variables) in Julia?

Tags: functional-programming, immutability, julia

In Julia, why is immutability a "property" of overall types (in the [Julia sense of the word](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/types/), so more akin to a struct or class in other languages) rather than variables?

e.g. In Rust (and I think most languages with support for immutability), whether something is immutable is set on specific variables rather than overall types - i.e. there are no separate `Vector` vs `ImmutableVector` structs. To create an immutable vector, I do `let v = Vec::new()`. To create a mutable one, I do `let mut v = Vec::new()`. `mut` is thus a keyword that can apply to any struct.

This seems more convenient, because you can make anything immutable, and variables are immutable by default (which the Julia folks want people to do as much as possible [1]). Are there pragmatic or performance gains with the Julia approach instead?

1: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13#issuecomment-11007166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is largely a semantic distinction. While somewhat less convenient than the Rust syntax, if you really want you can do the same thing in Julia with `abstract` types:

```
abstract MyType
type MyTypeMut <: MyType
    a::Int
end
immutable MyTypeImmut <: MyType
    a::Int
end
```

Now declare your variables using the appropriate `Mut`/`Immut` type, but for any function arguments that need type declarations, use `MyType`.

Answer (score 5):

> whether something is immutable is set on specific variables rather than overall types

I think there's some confusion here about what meaning we give to types and values.

In your example you give a mutable and immutable vector:

```
let v = Vec::new().
let mut v = Vec::new()
```

So these appear to have the same type, "Vec", yet somehow the second one is immutable. You've tagged it with an extra property of immutability via a new keyword, "mut".

You could imagine this property as part of the type as well, e.g.:

```
let v = Vec<Pure>::new().
let v = Vec<Mutable>::new().
```

Using a type parameter to pass in the mutable/immutable tag. One benefit is no need for an extra keyword, but it requires a type system that supports higher-order types.

The "mut" keyword is really just another way to tell the compiler about a particular property -- it adds "type" information. That information could also be passed directly in type syntax, if the type system was expressive enough. Either way, the compiler knows the property and can make optimizations regarding it.

So, in summary, even if mutability/effects are not part of the concrete type syntax, they are still logically part of the "type" as the compiler sees it. Tricks like 'mut' keywords are ways to annotate the type with this information, in the same way parameters to types behave in other languages.

Comment: In `let mut v = Vec::new()`, the `mut` makes `v` mutable, as immutability is the default in Rust.

Comment: Right. Going back to Rust, mutability/immutability *is* part of the type, but you can set it on a variable-by-variable basis. It's not set for all instances of a given type, like Julia. The difference is deeper than syntax. I'll try to edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: I think the point of this answer is that mutability vs immutability (as opposed to constness of bindings) is a feature of a type, not a variable. What Rust is doing here is implicitly creating *two* types for every type you declare – the mutable version and the immutable version.